# Open Graph Like for a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to like (increase the like count) a facebook page using open graph protocol.
I know user can like a URL which has open graph meta tags.

**I would like do the same for a facebook page. Please let me know is it possible and how it can be done?**

Thanks
@n!sh

Comment: No, it is _not_ possible. The og.likes action is for Open Graph objects, and only URLs “outside” of Facebook are considered as those.

Comment: Thanks.. So the only way is to use facebook social plugin, right?